# Tag cloud and Category list with gatsby-plugin-categories / gatsby-plugin-tags

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphiql, gatsby-plugin

I wanna create a tag cloud (or category list) which should link to the corresponding tagged articles and category. But in the queries I built only the `name` OR `slug` are concatenated because they are placed either in `fields` OR in `frontmatter` but not in one object

I use this two plugins which are widely used: https://github.com/rmcfadzean/gatsby-pantry

This is my current query:

```
{
  tags: allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}}}) {
    group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
      fieldValue
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            tags
          }
          frontmatter {
            tags
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMarkdownRemark": {
      "group": [
        {
          "fieldValue": "Another tag",
          "totalCount": 1,
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "fields": {
                  "tags": [
                    "another-tag",
                    "my-example",
                    "post"
                  ]
                },
                "frontmatter": {
                  "tags": [
                    "Another tag",
                    "My example",
                    "Post"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldValue": "Example",
          "totalCount": 1,
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "fields": {
                  "tags": [
                    "example",
                    "post"
                  ]
                },
                "frontmatter": {
                  "tags": [
                    "Example",
                    "Post"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldValue": "My example",
          "totalCount": 1,
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "fields": {
                  "tags": [
                    "another-tag",
                    "my-example",
                    "post"
                  ]
                },
                "frontmatter": {
                  "tags": [
                    "Another tag",
                    "My example",
                    "Post"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldValue": "Post",
          "totalCount": 2,
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "fields": {
                  "tags": [
                    "another-tag",
                    "my-example",
                    "post"
                  ]
                },
                "frontmatter": {
                  "tags": [
                    "Another tag",
                    "My example",
                    "Post"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "node": {
                "fields": {
                  "tags": [
                    "example",
                    "post"
                  ]
                },
                "frontmatter": {
                  "tags": [
                    "Example",
                    "Post"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

How can I get objects something like this:

```
{ "tags": 
  [
   { "slug": "another-tag", "frontmatter": "Another Tag"},
   { "slug": "example", "frontmatter": "Example"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My current approach is in the view itself. I iterate through the fields.tags and search for them in the array. I save the index and use it for frontmatter.tags (they are happily in the same order)

It is exactly that code:

```js
<ul className="tagcloud">
  {tags.group.map((tag, idx) => {
    var index = tag.edges[0].node.frontmatter.tags.indexOf(
      tag.fieldValue
    )

    return (
      <li key={idx}>
        <Link
          to={`/tags/${tag.edges[0].node.fields.tags[index]}`}
          className="transition link"
        >
          {tag.fieldValue}
        </Link>
      </li>
    )
  })}
</ul>
```